# haskell - state prepared at app startup and read from without parameters

Tags: haskell

I'm finishing a little GUI app in Haskell and right now adding translations support. On linux it's easy, I can use [hgettext](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hgettext), and it provides me with

```
getText :: String -> IO String
```

and in fact the authors [even recommend](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Internationalization_of_Haskell_programs_using_gettext) to use it like so:

```
__ :: String -> String
__ = unsafePerformIO . getText
```

It doesn't shock me, after all the texts are only displayed to the screen, it's all side-effects, and normally they don't change during the runtime of the application. I could do without the unsafePerformIO but I think it's OK although I never needed it so far in Haskell.

However my problem is that I can't get gettext to work on Windows and so I decided to roll my own system for windows. It should be pretty easy for my very moderate needs. I just want to parse the PO files and make myself a `Map String String` and I can have my function to get the translations. So at startup I would find out the current language and read the translation files... But then I would have to pass that `Map String String` all over the place in my program. To every dialog and then to every little function that'll ask the user whether he's sure to delete that item and so on... Wrapping the entire program in a reader monad would be absolutely overkill I think.

I was reading about memoization, also on top-level mutable state, but the solutions seem overkill. I could generate some hashes at build-time with some pretty serious template haskell magic but that also sounds wrong...

I wouldn't be shocked by some global state for that function with some sort of IORef (maybe I should be...) but I'm not even sure how I would code it...

Any clues on what I could do in this particular case?

Comment: I actually was working on an API to do simple translations recently, and my approach was essentially a `ReaderT (Map String String) m a` solution.  I don't think it's unreasonable to make all of your UI-facing functions live inside a reader monad, just factor out the actual behaviors to pure functions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Maybe I should give it a try. Didn't actually get to learn properly monad transformers yet, and I'm finishing my project and I consider windows a side-case, the main case being linux and gettext... But yes, this solution definitely sounds better... Still given the context I'll probably go the "ugly" way if there is no relatively convenient nice way.

Comment: Your UI is probably already happening in some monad, right?  Why is adding a reader feature to it overkill?

Comment: It's all in the IO monad currently, some pieces in the `Render` monad from cairo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty common to use the standard idiom for [top-level mutable state](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Top_level_mutable_state):

```
translations :: IORef (Map String String)
{-# NOINLINE translations #-}
translations = unsafePerformIO (newIORef Map.empty)
```

The `NOINLINE` pragma is important to make sure that it doesn't get duplicated by inlining.

In your case the type signature doesn't matter so much, but in other cases it's needed to make sure that it's monomorphic, otherwise it would be duplicated at each use site anyway.

You'd then need to make sure that you initialise it with some useful data before anything might read it.

Ideally you would just make it into a `Map String String` without the `IORef` and just call `unsafePerformIO (read_translations ...)` in the definition, but that would depend on whether all the parameters needed for that were available at that point.

Comment: well i was on that page, I can't completely understand how could I miss that code. But I like the idea, that would never cross my mind I think, to fill it in straight away with the right values... I need to make a FFI call to win32 api and to read some files to fill in that Map.. Filling it all in that unsafePerformIO top-level call might be problematic with error handling.. But then if I fail doing these things nothing good would happen anyway so what the heck I may end up doing it like that.

Comment: If the call does fail then the error would just be stored in the top-level value, and would be thrown every time something else tries to use that value. Part of the magic of lazy evaluation :-)

Comment: ...so you could catch it and fail more gracefully on startup, or default to a known language perhaps?